# AWS Databricks Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to import/export my data using AWS (by Amazon) using Databricks online IDE, but I am a beginner and I have no idea how to begin!

Thanks in advance
Antonio

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is to mount your S3 bucket first:

```
dbutils.fs.mount('s3a://<s3_key_id>:<s3_secret_key>@<your_bucket_name>', '/mnt/some_path')
```

then you should be able to import/export your data:
df.write.csv(path='/mnt/some_path/, header=True)

Or you can save the file to local file system, then upload to S3:

```
dbutils.fs.cp('/local_path/filename', 's3a://<s3_key_id>:<s3_secret_key>@<your_bucket_name/filename')
```